# Do all the function types form a subcategory of `Hask`?

Tags: haskell, types, programming-languages, computer-science, category-theory

[In Haskell, all the types form a category  named `Hask`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory#Translating_categorical_concepts_into_Haskell).

Function types are types.
Do all the function types form a subcategory of `Hask`?

Do all the non-function types form a subcategory of `Hask`?

I think both answers are yes. But I dont know if I am right.

Comment: What happened when you tried to write down the definitions of what the objects, arrows, and composition would be and tried to prove that the composition was associative? If it just worked, great, you have your answer. If you defined those three things and found composition was not associative, great, you have your answer. If you tried, but got stuck somewhere, great, you can improve your question by showing us how far you made it and why you're having trouble making further progress. But if you didn't even try... well, then, this question isn't appropriate for this forum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let `C` be any category having class `O` for its objects.

If `O'` is any subclass of `O` we can define a category `C'` taking `O'` as the objects, and keeping all the morphisms in `C` which still "make sense", i.e. which have source and target object in `O'`. Composition and identities are the same (restricted to `O'`).

`C'` is a subcategory of `C`. (A *full* subcategory, to be precise.)

You should check this claim yourself, by expanding all the definitions.

The examples you mention simply pick some special cases for `O'`, so they are subcategories.